# SQLAlchemy raw sql with list in where clause mssql pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I want to pass a list into my raw sql where clause but I keep getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)'
```

```
id = [1, 2, 3]
query = text("select * from table where col in :id")
conn.execute(query, {'id': tuple(id)})
```

This should work (I see them as solutions on StackOverflow) but maybe not for sqlserver?  How do I make it work for mssql?

Answer (score 1):

```py
id = [1, 2, 3]
query = text("select * from table where col in :id")    
query = query.bindparams(bindparam('id', expanding=True))
conn.execute(query, {'id': id})
```

as per OP @jole5646's edit on his own question.